# Hadoop Mapreduce using FileChannel, FileInputStream

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, filechannel

I want to use `FileChannel` in Hadoop Reducer for fast retrieval the data from file. With it, I can use `MappedByteBuffer` to map parts of file to memory. It is faster than other APIs when reading data (At least much faster than `DataInputStream`). However, I cannot find any solution to get `FileChannel` object from Hadoop API. Currently, I only find `FSDataInputStream` to read data from file.

How can I solve that?